# Upload checking in DB

Tags: c#, sql, epplus

I'm uploading an `xlsx` file in DB using the free library `EPPlus`.
This works fine and the uploading is visible in the database.
I wanna check the uploading status like "`upload successfull`" or "`upload failed`".

Is there a method that do this?

I hope I've been clear and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you upload the file. If it's not via ajax then you could redirect depending on success or failure.

```
try
{
    // Code to process upload
    Response.Redirect("/success.aspx");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Response.Redirect("/failure.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of a try catch block! THANK YOU SO MUCH!